# How I Can Add Action Methods(edit, delete, Detalis) in datatable using javescript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

I tried Adding edit method in js code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myTable').DataTable({

        "ajax": {
            "url": "/Admin/Product/AllProducts"

        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "description" },
            { "data": "price" },
            { "data": "category.name" },
            {

                data: "id",
                className: "dt-center editor-delete",
                orderable: false,

                "mRender": function (data) {
                    return
                         '<a href="/Admin/Product/Edit"id="' + data + '" >Edit</a>';
                }
            }
        ]
```

but when i did this browser say:

DataTables warning: table id=myTable - Requested unknown parameter 'id' for row 0, column 4. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the `error` because your `mRender` is decoreted incorrectly. You could try following way which is convenient and easy to debug.

**Asp.net Core Controller:**

```
public ActionResult IndexUserList()
        {
           
            return View();
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetUserList()
        {
            var userList = _context.Users.ToList();
            return Ok(userList);
        }
```

**HTML:**

```
<table id="userTable_info">
    <thead>
        <tr>
             <th>Id </th>
            <th>Name </th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Mobile</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tBody"> </tbody>
</table>
```

**Script:**

```
@section scripts {

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function DetailsFunc(data) {
        alert("User Id:" + data + " Details!");
    }
    function EditFunc(data) {
        alert("User Id:" + data + " will be Edited!");
    }
    function DeleteFunc(data) {
        alert("User Id:" + data + " will be deleted!");
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'http://localhost:5094/Todo/GetUserList',
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                $.each(response, function (index, value) {
                    var tr = "<tr>";
                    tr += "<td>" + value.name + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + value.fname + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + value.email + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + value.mobile + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + "<input type='button' id='" + value.id + "' onclick='DetailsFunc(" + value.id + ")' value='Details'>" + "  " + "<input type='button' id='" + value.id + "' onclick='EditFunc(" + value.id + ")' value='Edit'>" + "  " + "<input type='button' id='" + value.id + "' onclick='DeleteFunc(" + value.id + ")' value='Delete'>" + "</td>" + "</tr>";
                   
                    $("#tBody").append(tr);
                });
                $("#userTable_info").DataTable();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

}

**Note:** Please note that, keep your `property name` as `lower case` in `client side` no matter if they are in `upper case` in backend. For instance, use `value.name` instead of `value.Name`

**Output:**

[image]